# Linux: everyday at the same time, my MySQL would shutdown, revert to previous version, and then restart on its own. How to fix this?

Tags: linux, mysql

I recently migrated from MySQL 5.0 to Percona Server 5.1. I used

```
yum remove mysql-server mysql-client
```

to remove the old version. Then I installed Percona Server using `yum`.

Since then, everyday at the same time, my `mysqld` would shut down and restart on its own. The strange thing is that when it comes back up, it would no longer be Percona Server 5.1 but the previous version: MySQL 5.0!

And then I'd remove MySQL 5.0 and install Percona Server 5.1 once again. But the same thing would happen the next day at the same time: shut down, revert to old version, and restart.

I guess something is shutting down MySQL everyday at the same time. And then it reinstall the old version of MySQL and startup the old version.

How do I find out what is going on? And how do I fix this? This is driving me crazy.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

OK so it seems like cpanel is the problem here. Can anyone tell me what is cpanel doing here and how can it "bring back" the old version of MySQL? And how could I fix it?

Comment: your not using a cpanel server are you? because that would do it for sure

Comment: I am using a cpanel server. But I'm logging in through ssh. So what is cpanel doing exactly and how do i fix it? I don't know anything about cpanel. Thanks.

Comment: see my answer for info but its the daily auto updates reinstalling mysql because cpanel manages the system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable MySQL in cPanel: Server Configuration -> Update Config and set MySQL: never

Try find yum command in cron:

```
  # find /etc/cron* -type f -exec grep yum {} \; -print
  # find /var/spool/cron/ -type f -exec grep yum {} \; -print
```

Or find time in yum log(/var/log/messages):

```
  # grep yum /var/log/messages
  Mar  1 15:29:29 localhost yum: Installed: mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_5.4.i386
```

Then run `last` to find user account who install mysql:

```
  # last
  ooshro   pts/0        10.0.2.2         Tue Mar  1 15:12   still logged in
```

Comment: yum log only shows me removing the old MySQL 5.0 and installing Percona Server 5.1. It doesn't show how MySQL 5.0 was "brought back" to life even after I've specifically removed it:

Comment: disable MySQL in cPanel, I update answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using cpanel so you need to disable the mysql system updates from update settings in WHM, then you can install percona over the top without it being replaced daily by cpanel when it does its usual updates

If you only want mysql 5.1 you can also upgrade to that via WHM, because using a custom db install may probably not be supported by cpanel